# Python: method invoke by read a file

Tags: python

I have a excel having data like below:

**Data.xlsx**

```
Method_Name | Argument_01 | Argument _02
Func1       | val1        | val2
Func2       | val3        | val4
```

Now my question is:

How to read the function name and arguments from `Data.xlsx` file and invoke the method `Func1` and pass the arguments `(val1,val2)` using python?

If provide me a code on that using python it would be very very helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are looking to read excel files [this](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a file is trivial. Just google it. Next, you can use `eval()`. Something like this.

```
def method1(val1):
    print(val1 + 1)

s1 = 'method1'
s2 = '99'
eval(s1 + '(' + s2 + ')')
# 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its working.. :)